# Remove individual td's during deleting rows using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

In my web application, I was dynamically adding/deleting rows from my HTML table using jQuery.

I had a requirement that I needed to delete individual td elements(and not entire row).

My jQuery code is as follows:

```
$(function () {

    /* adding new row to existing table */
    // HTML template of a row
    $("#contactInfo").each(function () {
        $("button.addCommentRow", this).live('click', function () {

            var curr_row = $(this).closest('tr');
            var html = '<tr><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> ' + col_ninth + '</td> <td><button type="button" class="addCommentRow">+</button> <button type="button" class="deleteCommentRow">-</button> </td> </tr>';

            var newRow = $(html).insertAfter(curr_row); // add after the last
            newRow.find('.addCommentRow, .deleteCommentRow').button();
            newRow.find('.deleteCommentRow').button().click(function () {

                newRow.find("td:nth-child(9)").remove();
                newRow.find("td:nth-child(10)").remove();

            });
        });
    });
});
```

So, on deleting I wanted to remove the 9th and the 10th td element from my row.

The above code(only the deletion part) does not seem to work.
Any ideas/suggestions to get working will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Pritish.

Comment: Surely this is going to play havoc with your layout, as table rows need matching or colspanned cells to render correctly.  Can you not just delete the contents of these cells instead?

Comment: @Paddy : I can delete the contents the cells as well.
How would I do that?

Comment: @Bob : Sorry, I'd missed adding the HTML, I've edited my original question to include the html.

Comment: Please look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/QTwWn/1/ . Tell me if it is what you are looking at/is what is wrong.

Comment: @Pritish, if you can delete cell contents, why not just set innerHTML to ""?

Comment: @Pritish - What's the result if you use `.empty()` instead of `.remove()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try something like this, try the **Demo** : **http://jsfiddle.net/HXB4Z/**

**HTML**  :

```
<table border=2>
    <tr>
        <td>jQuery</td>
        <td>mootools</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dojo</td>
        <td>FUEL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Raphael</td>
        <td>Rico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>SproutCore</td>
        <td>Lively Kernel</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**javascript** :

```
$(function() {
   $('tr')
       .find('td')
       .append('<input type="button" value="Delete" class="del"/>')
       .parent()//traversing to 'tr' Element
       .append('<td><input type="button" value="Delete row" class="delrow" /></td>');

    $('.del').click(function() {
       $(this).parent().remove(); //Deleting TD element
    });

    $('.delrow').click(function(){
       $(this).parent().parent().remove(); //Deleting the Row (tr) Element
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Irwin. You probably want something like this:

```
newRow.find("td:nth-child(9)").html('');
newRow.find("td:nth-child(10)").html('');
```

Comment: This is *not* a good idea, you should use `.empty()` here, since you're leaking memory with `.html('')`

Comment: I certain hope JavaScript would take care of the garbage collection there, or am I too optimistic? But I do agree that empty() is more elegant in this case.

Comment: @Nick : .empty() seems to work, except for one small thing though.
I also want to make sure, if the 10th td element that I'm deleting, if it happens to the last one haviny any cell contents, then delete the tr also after that. The reason I say this, is with only .empty() of the individual td elements it's leaving behind row borders after deletions.

Comment: @William - JavaScript won't cleanup the event handlers on `.deleteCommentRow` from `$.cache`, which `.remove()` and `.empty()` will :)

Comment: @nick, here the guy want to `delete` the element. If `.empty()` is used it just makes the content of the element to **empty**, which means that its not going to delete the Element

Comment: @Avinash - Yes, but removing a `<td>` is a bad idea, it'll FUBAR the table layout in most cases, that's why emptying the cells would be a better approach, unless you're accounting for the lost cells in other ways.